# Spring Batch Item Reader passing file object instead of resource name?

Tags: spring-batch, spring-integration

Generally, ItemReader has resource name as attribute, Can we pass file object to any of the Implementation of ItemReader.

I am using 3 version of Spring Batch API.

UPDATED :::

```
<bean id="cvsFileItemReader" class="org.springframework.batch.item.file.FlatFileItemReader" scope="step">

    <!-- Read a csv file -->
    <property name="resource" value="classpath:cvs/I_10000_3ColRem_input_File.csv" />

    <property name="lineMapper">
        <bean class="org.springframework.batch.item.file.mapping.DefaultLineMapper">

            <!-- split it -->
            <property name="lineTokenizer">
                <bean
                    class="org.springframework.batch.item.file.transform.DelimitedLineTokenizer">
                    <property name="names" value="customerId,year,month,numPurchases,sow,purchaseAmt,cm,mc,multiChannel,loyalty,productReturn,relationDur,cb" />
                </bean>
            </property>

            <property name="fieldSetMapper">

                <!-- return back to reader, rather than a mapped object. -->

                <!-- map to an object -->
                <bean
                    class="org.springframework.batch.item.file.mapping.BeanWrapperFieldSetMapper">
                    <property name="prototypeBeanName" value="testCLV" />
                    <property name="customEditors">
                      <map>
                        <entry key="java.lang.Double">
                             <ref local="doubleEditor" />
                        </entry>
                  </map>
                </property>
                </bean>
            </property>
        </bean>
    </property>

</bean>
```

My App.java looks like

```
ApplicationContext context = 
            new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext(springConfig);

    JobLauncher jobLauncher = (JobLauncher) context.getBean("jobLauncher");
    Job job = (Job) context.getBean("reportJob");



    try {
        long a, b;
        a = System.currentTimeMillis();
        JobExecution execution = jobLauncher.run(job, new JobParameters());

        b = System.currentTimeMillis();
        System.out.println("Exit Status : " + execution.getStatus());
        System.out.println("jobLauncher.run "+(b-a)+"mil to execute. ("+((b-a)/1000)+" seconds)");
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    System.out.println("Done");
```

My requirement is follow ::

Through web-application user will upload a file, from which i extracted inputStream

Let say i have a streamInput obj as 'streamInput', how could i inject this to resource of ItemReader and run my job.

Comment: I think no. Why do you need this feature?

Comment: My requirement is to process a file which is uploaded by web-application, so i will have a file object. If i save the file on server, then it may run into memory issue. Do you have any solution for the problem.

Comment: I think spring-integration can resolve the problem (but I'm can't help you,sorry). Tag question with 'spring-integration' for wider visibility

Answer (score 0):

You can create a `Resource` from an `InputStream` (`InputStreamResource`) which you could get from a `File` object.  You can read more about the `InputStreamResource` here: http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/core/io/InputStreamResource.html

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply, Please see the updated text above

Comment: Just thinking off the top of my head, I'd use a `FactoryBean` to provide the `Resource`.  That would allow you to set the `InputStream` in the `FactoryBean` so that when you call the job, the `FactoryBean` would provide the `Resource`.

Comment: Thanks Minella for your quick reply, Do you have any sample code which demonstrate what u have said above?